# Cucumber on Jenkins - Can't run app build in simulator

Tags: ios, jenkins, automated-tests, cucumber, calabash

I'm setting up Calabash automated tests for an iOS app on a Mac-based Jenkins CI with a declarative Pipeline script. The script checks out repositories, builds the app, copies app binary into the right place for Cucumber to find, etc. Everything works up to the point when Cucumber is started. It launches the iOS simulator but then fails with the following error (it continues to go through all test cases but every one of them fails with this error):

> An error was encountered processing the command (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=5):
>    Failed to copy /h/jobs/calabash_pipeline_ios/workspace/scm/calabash/iOS/apps/foo.app to file:///Users/foouser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E6E71772-FD95-467C-B37E-0096EF3DD0A8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Z5VAtJ/extracted/foo.app/
>
> This usually means your CoreSimulator processes need to be restarted.
>
> You can restart the CoreSimulator processes with this command:
>
> $ bundle exec run-loop simctl manage-processes

As suggested I'm running `bundle exec run-loop simctl manage-processes` in the script before the Cucumber steps but it's not helping.

Does anyone know why the copy operation failed?

Comment: Did you consider invetigating the error message "This usually means your CoreSimulator processes need to be restarted."? Is the CoreSimulator process available? To me this sounds like a setup issue. Something is missing on your CI box.